# Plotting 3 graphs in a 2-1 layout in R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to obtain 3 plots in a single figure in R with a distribution as shown in the image below? The plots must have the same width, and plot C should be centered.

```
-----   -----
| A |   | B |
-----   -----
    -----
    | C |
    -----
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with the `layout(...)` function.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
hist(mtcars$wt)
hist(mtcars$mpg)
hist(mtcars$disp)
```

[image]

So `layout(...)` takes a matrix where each element corresponds to a plot number. In this case, [1,1] corresponds to the first plot, [1,2] corresponds the the second plot, and [2,1:2] corresponds to the third plot.

This example is taken with slight modification from [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html).

If you want the bottom plot to be the same "width" as the two above, you can tweak the margins for that plot.

```
par(mar=c(4,4,2,2))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
hist(mtcars$wt)
hist(mtcars$mpg)
par(mar=c(2,14,2,14))
hist(mtcars$disp)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! The example is quite useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can easily get equal widths by using `layout(mat = matrix(c(1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0),nrow = 2, byrow = T))` instead. Each plot is 2 cells wide, bottom row is padded by two empty cells.