# Plotting 5 graphs in a 3-2 layout in R

Tags: r, plot

```
-----   -----   -----
| A |   | B |   | C |
-----   -----   ----
    -----   -----
    | D |   | E |
    -----   -----
```

or

```
    -----   -----  
    | A |   | B |   
    -----   -----  
-----   -----   -----
| C |   | D |   | E |
-----   -----   -----
```

I have 5 graphs and I wanted to put into 1 plot, structured as above. Got some hit from this post:
[Plotting 3 graphs in a 2-1 layout in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231830/plotting-3-graphs-in-a-2-1-layout-in-r), to use layout() functio, but just couldn't make it right.

Anyone can help? thanks very much.

#### update

---

Just attached my plot, after fixing the structure. Thanks very much for the help.
[image: my plot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with `layout`. Just make a 6*2 grid and make sure each plot is 2 cells wide. Pad the 2-plot row with some zeros to align them nicely.

```
layout(mat = matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,
                      0,4,4,5,5,0), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
layout.show(n = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can get the above plot using layout as, thought you cannot divide the width of the second row with odd columns.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,4,5), 2, 3, byrow = TRUE))
hist(as.matrix(1:10))
hist(as.matrix(1:10))
hist(as.matrix(1:10))
hist(as.matrix(1:10))
hist(as.matrix(1:10))
```

[image]