# Plotting 3 Graphs in a 2-1 Configuration

Tags: r

I am trying to plot 3 graphs in the same plot, with the third graph in its own row below the first two graphs. This is what I have currently

```
m1<-ggplot(Xmin)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=V), color="navy", size=0.75)
m3<-ggplot(Xmin)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=n),color="darkblue", size=0.75)
m2<-ggplot(Xmin)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=m, color= "Activation and Deactivation"), size=0.75)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=h, color= "Inactivation and Restoration"), size=0.75)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
```

but when I run that I get a blank graph. The graph below is the closest I could get using gridExtra, but I want the bottom graph to be larger to display the key and just more of that graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3p74.png)

This is what I want the graph configuration to be:
[image]

Comment: is it just a typo or is there a " missing in the third line? it should be
`m2<-ggplot(Xmin)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=m, color= "Activation and Deactivation"), size=0.75) + geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=h, color= "Inactivation and Restoration"), size=0.75)`

Comment: it's a typo in the post!

Comment: Do you actually plot the three graphs after your call to `layout()`? I.e., do you call `m1;m2;m3` after `layout(...)`?

Comment: I based my code off of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231830/plotting-3-graphs-in-a-2-1-layout-in-r. I went back to my original file and changed the order to have layout(...) first and then m1,m2, and m3 below it, but I still get a blank graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gridExtra`:

```
# install.packages("gridExtra")
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(m1, m2, m2, widths = c(1, 1),
             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2),
                                   c(3, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(m1,m3,ncol=2), #first row with two plots in two columns
m2, nrow=2) #second row with one plot spanning two columns
```